# Java Formatting Date String

Tags: java, string, date, formatting

I need to convert this `20140815`

into `15.08.2014` and into `15.08.2014 00:00:00`

How do I do that, what opportunities are there in Java

Comment: What research have you done so far, and what have you tried? Hint: `SimpleDateFormat`...

Comment: And Date object has no format. only String has format. You want to do string->string conversion or parsing string to Date?

Comment: i want only a string conversion / parsing and not string to date

Comment: @JonSkeet date format? Too complicated and unnecessary. This can be done with simple string manipulation. Simple==best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `SimpleDateFormat` as follows

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");

Date date = inputFormat.parse("20140815");
String result = outputFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: It would be worth specifying both a time zone (UTC) and a `Locale` (e.g. US English). Even though this *particular* format doesn't use any locale-specific symbols, it's a good habit to get into... and as there are time zones where midnight doesn't exist, you can get some weird behaviour that way if you're not careful, too.

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with Dates... just use Strings:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("(....)(..)(..)", "$3.$2.$1");
```

or

```
String output = input.replaceAll("(....)(..)(..)", "$3.$2.$1 00:00:00");
```

Comment: You would bother with date parsing formatting because: a) it will validate that you really *have* got appropriate date; b) it invites you to actually maintain a more sensible representation (rather than string) for longer. I'm always suspicious of "convert from date format X to date format Y" tasks, because normally you should parse date-related data as *soon* as you can, and format it as *late* as you can. Those two points of code are rarely the same point, in my experience.